# How to manage multiple roles and users in MS Access 2010 application?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, membership-provider, membership, user-roles

we have to build an application solely using MS Access all the forms have to be designed in MS access and DB is also in MS access.

what will be the best way to implement such an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your headline doesn't really match your question, but I can tell you that Access got rid of user-level security in 2010.  The best way to do it is to make it table-driven.

Keep one table with users names, their password (using an encrypted field), and their security level.  Then, whenever you launch a form you check the table to make sure the user has clearance to view it.

You will also need a login screen to make sure the user has access to the database in the first place, then you can just hide that form instead of closing it so you can always refer to the user's name when you check each new form for clearance.

Comment: thank you , the main issue that we are facing is the Question that i have asked in the details section i have just explained that how we are working.